# Make line from string red if quote character found

Tags: php, html, preg-match

I'm trying to make each line from a string red if a quote character of ">" is found. I'm doing this with a certain database query result, and it works; however it brings back an HTML line break after each "quote match" like this:

```
text
>text

text
text
```

**Why is this?**

```
function quote_colors($text) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach ($lines as $index => $line) {
        if (preg_match('/^>/', strip_tags($line))) {
            $lines[$index] = "<span style='color:red;'>{$line}</span>";
        }
    }
    $text = implode("\n", $lines);

    return $text;
}

echo nl2br(quote_colors($row['post']));
```

UPDATE -- this is the result with red text:

```
<span style="color:#AABC68;">>test<br /></span><br />
```

And without:

```
<span style="color:#AABC68;">>test</span>
```

Comment: Might be a stretch, but have you ruled out any excess newline or carriage return characters on these lines in the unprocessed text?

Comment: Yes, the database string is simply four lines that say "text", with the second one with an arrow

Comment: So there were carriage returns after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explode the text by line:

```
function quote_colors($text) {
    return preg_replace('~^>[^\r\n]*~m', '<span style="color:red;">$0</span>', $text);
}
```

The m modifier changes the meaning of the `^` anchors to *start of the line*, then you only need to match the lines that begin with `>`

Comment: Nice code clean-up! Still the initial problem persists... Ivan's answer seems too unnecessarily bulky with the HTML/CSS

Comment: Well each line of the string has a <br/> in the database, if that means much?

Comment: @user1228907: No, you are right, it was because the dot matches the carriage return character `\r`. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt you generate a constant type of text (each line with a span) than set the distance between rows using css:

```
function quote_colors($text) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    foreach ($lines as $index => $line) {
        if (preg_match('/^>/', strip_tags($line))) {
            $lines[$index] = "<span class='color-row' style='color:red;'>".htmlspecialchars($line)."</span>";
        } else {
            $lines[$index] = "<span  class='color-row' style='color:black;'>".htmlspecialchars($line)."</span>";
        }

    }
    $text = implode("\n", $lines);

    return $text;
}

echo nl2br(quote_colors($row['post']));
```

example css:

```
.color-row{
  height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Your text's End-of-lines are encoded in Windows style, `\r\n`, but you're exploding on the `\n`. With the untouched text, `nl2br()` can handle this.  But when you replace your temporary a line by encapsulating it with the span, it retains the carriage-return character, `\r`, and `nl2br()` turns this into an HTML line break tag.  I recommend normalizing your line breaks either prior to database insertion or after pulling the text from the database, so you only need to account for one EOL style from there on.